# Maven module using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I like to configure my applications in maven by creating modules like;

```
<groupId>com.app</groupId>
<artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>app-api</module>
    <module>app-impl</module>
    <module>app-web</module>
</modules>
```

The modules then use the 'example-app' as the parent.

Now I want use 'spring-boot' for my web application.

Is there a way to configure maven so that my 'app-web' is a spring-boot application?

The problem I'm facing is that you have to use spring-boot as a parent.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You don't have to use the spring-boot-starter-parent, it's just a way  to get started quickly. All it provides are dependency management and plugin management. You can do both yourself, and you can use the spring-boot-dependencies (or equivalently the parent) to manage dependencies if you want a halfway step.  To do that, use [`scope=import`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) like this

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: slight edit - you need to add a <dependencies> element below <dependencyManagement>, otherwise it seems to work for me too.

Comment: @Dave What does "or equivalently the parent" mean exactly? Could you include that in the example, too?

Comment: I meant that (as far as dependencyManagement goes) scope=import or using that POM as a parent are equivalent. (When you use it as a parent you get other features, like plugin configuration.)

Comment: When I replaced declaration of spring-boot-starter-parent with depdendency to "spring-boot-dependencies" artifact then I get the following error: no main manifest attribute, in target/my-app-0.1.0.jar

Does it mean that I have to copy all the plugins from spring-boot-starter-parent?

Comment: I guess it means you have to copy at least one of them :-). If it's a regular jar then maybe just the spring-boot plugin.

Comment: This gets me "halfway"? What's the rest? I add this, but it doesn't work for me, that is, it doesn't build a standalone jar as I expected.

Comment: The spring-boot plugin can be used to build an executable jar (the goal is called "repackage" I think).

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative, is to include in the parent pom, the parent declaration for spring boot, as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257409/maven-configuration-with-spring-boot-multi-modules-run-application-in-intell)

example-app pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    // rest of the example-app pom declarations
</project>
```

After that, in the modules poms (app-web, app-impl, etc.), you declare example-app as parent, but now you can include the starter dependencies as you would normally do in a regular project.

app-web pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>app-web</name>
    <artifactId>app-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    // rest of the app-web pom declarations
</project>
```

Regarding version management, what i used in these examples aren't exactly the best practices, but since is out of the scope of the question i skipped dependencyManagement and parent properties usage.

Also, if there is a starter that is used in every module, you can declare the dependency in the parent pom and then all the modules will inherit it (for example *spring-boot-starter-test*)